# Problemas de versión en una aplicación Android que pasará de versión beta a versión final

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

A ver si me pueden ayudar con esto.

Hace un tiempo yo publiqué en Google Play Store [mi primera app Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.deiverbum.liturgiacatolica&hl=es_419) en una versión beta.

Dicha versión beta lleva ya tres actualizaciones, o sea que en realidad la versión actual sería una versión `beta 3`.

El gradle actual indica la versión de esta manera:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.dominio.aplicacion"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName '3.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Ahora yo quiero publicar la **versión final** de dicha aplicación.

El problema es que la primera versión (beta) de la app, la primera que publiqué en Play Store, tenía esto:

```
        versionName '1.0'
```

Si yo vuelvo a poner esto en el gradle actual, recibo un aviso diciendo que estoy haciendo un *downgrade* de mi aplicación. O sea, Android Studio entiende que estoy pasando de la versión 3.0 a la versión 1.0 de la app.

### La pregunta

**Si yo compilo mi código final usando `versionName '1.0'` ¿tendré algún problema al subir mi versión final a Play Store?**

**¿Recibirán los usuarios un aviso de actualización, si Play Store interpreta la actualización como un *downgrade*, cuando en realidad es un *upgrade*?**

Comment: En principio siempre debes aumentar el número de la versión, te aconsejo que uses 1.1 1.2 1.3 etc... de todas maneras que la versión final sea 3.0 no influirá en nada en tus usuarios, simplemente el android play developer necesita saber que es una versión nueva

Comment: Google Play es _curioso_ para las versiones. Cometí un fallo tipográfico en mi app, y desde entonces ya no tenía la versión 4.1 sino la 41 y he tenido que ir subiendo a partir de ahí. Si encuentras solución a esto igual puedo volver a los dígitos normales, aunque funcionalmente no afecta a nada, está bien tener las versiones "ordenadas".

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro cuando dices *he tenido que ir subiendo a partir de ahí*  **¿significa que Google Play no te dejó subir una versión con un número inferior al 41?** Es lo que me temo... no puedo saber lo que pasará porque aún no tengo la actualización terminada para subirla. Aunque tengo otra esperanza y que quizá al pasar de la versión beta a la versión final me permita empezar de nuevo con la v. 1.0... no lo sé.

Comment: Correcto. Si ponía una versión con un número más bajo la rechazaba diciendo que no podía remplazar la versión actual por una más baja. Al final me di por vencido y dejé de intentarlo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro agradecería una respuesta en ese sentido para dar este asunto por cerrado. Esa era mi principal duda, la cual queda confirmada con lo que me dices. Con respecto al paso de beta a definitiva investigaré lo que pueda ocurrir y si no encuentro nada volveré con otra pregunta.

Comment: Mirando la documentación, parece que puede haber una posibilidad jugando con los valores de `versionCode` y `versionName`, aunque no me termina de quedar claro. Probaré luego a ver si puedo volver mi aplicación a la versión 4.1 (versionName) aunque internamente siga siendo la 41 (versionCode) y actualizaré mi respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano registra un versionCode posterior, en este caso seguramente lo tienes en el AndroidManifest.xml  el versionName puedes agregar el que desees incluso repetirlo entre versiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Si yo compilo mi código final usando versionName '1.0' ¿tendré algún
problema al subir mi versión final a Play Store?**

Puedes usar el mismo versionName no importa si todas tus actualizaciones tienen el mismo, en realidad el que determina una nueva versión es el versionCode

> [versionName](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html): string usada como el número de versión que se muestra a
>   los usuarios. Esta configuración se puede especificar como una string
>   sin procesar o como una referencia a un recurso de string.
>
> [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html): valor entero usado como número de versión interna. Este
>   número se usa solo para determinar si una versión es más reciente que
>   otra; los números más altos indican versiones más recientes.

El [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) se debe encontrar en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` o en tu `build.gradle`, siendo siempre este archivo el que sobreescribe cualquier configuración dentro de `AndroidManifest.xml`

---

**¿Recibirán los usuarios un aviso de actualización, si Play Store interpreta la actualización como un downgrade, cuando en realidad es un upgrade?**

únicamente se interpretará como nueva actualización si tu .apk tiene definido un  [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) mayor, en realidad no puedes subir un "downgrade". Si defines el mismo [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html)  o uno menor no será posible agregar el release.

Si deseas subir una versión final puedes agregarla como beta, realizar pruebas y posteriormente publicarla a producción.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o puedes directamente subir tu .apk a producción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al agregar un nuevo .apk en "beta" o "producción" de una aplicación con el mismo packagename, tiene que tener un [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) mayor al anterior.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes poner una versión más baja que la última versión de la aplicación. Eso se indica en la documentación de Google Play para "[Actualizar tus aplicaciones](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=es-ES)" (énfasis mío):

> Cuando estés listo para modificar tu archivo APK, asegúrate de
>   actualizar también el código de versión de tu aplicación para que los
>   usuarios reciban la actualización.
>
> Utiliza la siguiente lista de comprobación para asegurarte de que tu
>   nuevo APK esté listo para que los usuarios realicen la actualización:
>
> - El nombre de paquete del archivo APK actualizado debe ser el mismo que el de la versión actual.
> - **El código de versión debe ser superior al código de la versión actual**.  Consulta más información sobre cómo [crear versiones de tus
>     aplicaciones](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html).
> - La firma del archivo APK actualizado debe coincidir con la firma de la versión actual.

---

Y en el enlace de [Cómo controlar la versión de tu app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) en la documentación de Android se añade un poco más sobre el tema. Se indica que `versionName` "no tiene otro propósito que mostrarse ante los usuarios" y de `versionCode` dice:

> [...] Puedes establecer el valor en cualquier número entero que desees; sin embargo, debes asegurarte de que en cada versión de tu app que siga se use un valor mayor. El sistema no impone este comportamiento, pero aumentar el valor con cada versión sucesiva es la regla.
>
> Normalmente, lanzarás la primera versión de tu app con versionCode fijado en 1, y luego aumentarás el valor en progresión continua en cada versión, sin importar si la versión es principal o secundaria. Esto significa que el valor versionCode no tiene necesariamente una fuerte semejanza con la versión de lanzamiento de la app que ve el usuario (consulta versionName, a continuación). Los servicios de apps y publicación no deben mostrar el valor de la versión a los usuarios.

Lo que deja la puerta abierta a que subas una actualización con un `versionName` más bajo mientras que el `versionCode` seguiría subiendo. Dejarían de estar sincronizados, pero teóricamente sería posible y no importaría porque lo que ve el usuario es el `versionName`.

**^ OJO: no he probado lo que digo en el párrafo anterior, por lo que podría no funcionar**. Y la información en la versión en español de la página parece *contradictoria* con la versión en inglés (donde se especifica que `versionCode` es usado para proteger de *downgrades* a los usuarios).